# is $_REQUEST dangerous even if you clean it?

Tags: php, request

I know `$_REQUEST` is bad because it contains cookie data as well.

Is it still bad to use `$_REQUEST` if we use some sort of clean function to it? Would someone be able to elaborate?

Comment: If you're talking about using it to pass the values to a database query, just use something that supports prepared statements (such as [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)) and you won't have to worry about it for the most part.

Comment: And the danger comes from what, may I ask? Any param in $_REQUEST can be sent via POST, GET _and_ cookie, if server is set up correspondingly. And each of this channels may be compromised.

Comment: @Matt - can you clarify what you mean by 'for the most part'?

Comment: @Matt Yes, defining `use $_REQUEST` would be most helpful for the OP here. )

Comment: @andrewsi nothing in life is a guarantee. From http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/: *"...using prepared statements will **help** protect you from SQL injection attacks."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_REQUEST` is not specifically dangerous.  Any user input can be an attack and should be treated as such. For any input medium `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIE`, use an appropriate method `intval()`, `preg_match()`, ... to verify that the value you receive is something you expect.

For example if you expect a file name and intend to send it to the user, make sure it does not contain `..` or `/` so the user won't be able to access your filesystem.

If you want to insert a user generated value in a database, make sure you are escaping your values, using the old `mysql_real_escape_string`, or better PDO or mysqli prepared statements.